# Rails 5 font files having extensions .woff are can't be precompiles in AWS EB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, precompile

I am trying to deploy rails 5(ruby 2.5 with passenger-standalone) application in AWS EB and I am getting following error when precompiling .woff files.

```
Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ba0c59deb5450f5cb41b3f93609ee2d0d995415877ddfa223e8a8a7533474f07.woff (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I am not sure what is the issue here but when I remove first .woff file then it's failed when precompiling next .woff(I have more than one .woff files).

Same code working fine in DigitalOcean with Cloud66.

I also have following code in assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```

Is there any problem in precompile .woff files in AWS EB ?

I am ready to provide more details if need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do u call in css file ?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found the issue. I have used web-packer and before pre-compilation it requires node and yard packages should be installed in machine before start precompile. After adding script to install these packages all are working fine.

Following is enough to precompile these font files.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)\z/
```